# Git config not located in default path

Tags: git, path, config

When I run "git config --system core.longpaths true" in CMD I get an error "could not lock config file %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%/.gitconfig: No such file or directory". I know that the reason is that my .gitconfig file is located not in a default path.

Is there any way to solve this? Can I pass somehow path to my config file?

Comment: It is is not in the default path how do you expect Git to find it later?

Comment: I mean it is not located in the path specified in post. Git finds this file well in other cases, but in this one it has a problem

Comment: May be you want `git config --global` ?

Comment: As @phd hinted : there is a difference between `git config --system` (do stuff with a *system-wide* git config file, which is generally in a place where you must be root/administrator to edit it) and `git config --global` (which is actually global to your user account only, is located in your `$HOME/.gitconfig`, and can be edited with your normal user account)

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between :

- `git config --system` : do stuff with a *system-wide* git config file, which is generally in a place where you must be root/administrator to edit it

and

- `git config --global` (which is actually global to your user account only) : the file is located in your `$HOME/.gitconfig`, and can be edited with your normal user account

---

You very probably want to run

```
git config --global core.longpaths true
```